# Autocomplete for UIMA Ruta in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, perspective, uima, ruta

Is there a way to have the autocomplete function when coding in UIMA Ruta on Eclipse? For instance, when I type `FEA`, I could get a suggestion like `FEATURE("","")`.

The Eclipse version I use is Mars 2 and for UIMA the following:

- UIMA Tools (with Runtime) 2.9.0
- UIMA Ruta Workbench 2.2.1

I guess this is an Eclipse-specific issue but given there's a UIMA Ruta Perspective and all that, I thought to ask if someone has managed to have this extremely useful feature when coding.

Comment: The autocompletion is not well maintained, but should acutally work for your example, only the name of the condition but not the arguments. Did you try to update the workbench? The current version is 2.6.1.

Comment: Thanks! I followed your suggestion and it helped! A follow-up question: is there a way that I edit the autocomplete suggestions, so that for example I eventually get the FEATURE command with the extra quotes and comma? Also, can I add ones that I'd like?

Comment: You can add your own templates at Menu->Window->Preferences->UIMA Ruta->Editor->Templates. However, I fear that templates are broken in current versions.

Comment: That was very helpful indeed. Eventually, there was no need (as far as I can tell) to get a newer version of the Workbench, so, for compatibility reasons, I switched back to the old one. Everything's working perfectly (with the autocompletion), so I'm ok. Thanks again!